# Icons not showing in my KendoUI for JQuery Grid

Tags: jquery, css, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-ui-grid

I have a KendoUI for JQuery grid, and as you can see in the screenshot below, all of the paging icons are not showing.

[image]

I have added the necessary stylesheet references.

[image]

And I have made sure that the stylesheets themselves and the .PNG files referenced in them are in my solution.

[image]

[image]

When I run the solution, I use Google Chrome.

At this point, I am at a loss as to what I'm doing wrong. If anyone knows anything, please help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I do not see the required fonts folder:

```
\kendo\fonts
\kendo\fonts\DejaVu
\kendo\fonts\glyphs
    KendoUIGlyphs.eot
    KendoUIGlyphs.svg
    KendoUIGlyphs.ttf
    KendoUIGlyphs.woff
    ...
```

I see you are not putting them in a kendo subfolder, but that should not matter as long as the relative paths are the same.

Comment: Yep, that did the trick! Thank you so much for your help! I really wish Telerik's documentation of the KendoUI Grid had included this.

Comment: I searched for it but I never saw it. All I saw was their HTML example code which referred to a couple of .js and .css files. That was it.

Comment: I was being sarcastic. Kendo documentation sucks.