# Icons are not loading in Internet explorer when i keep no-cache,no-store in cache control

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc

We are implementing security in our application developed in ASP Net MVC aadn Kendo UI. The changes making issue in loading icons.

Code change: Web.config

```
 <add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache, no-store,max-age=0" />
 <add name="Pragma" value="no-cache" />
```

I am losing icons(dropdown,filter - Kendo icons) in internet explorer after i deploy web.config in web server.

As part of security, I should have this change in place and application should up and running.

Please provide suggestions/solutions.

Note: Changes are working fine in my locla environment.

Comment: Make sure you have deployed all the glyphs, etc: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52186657/icons-not-showing-in-my-kendoui-for-jquery-grid

Comment: Thanks for the response .I have kendo icons in respective folder as mentioned above.But i am missing icons in **Internet explorer only and when i keep cache settings** as mentioned in heading.Where as it fine in google chrome and edge